# Spatio-temporal clustering Algorithm

Tags: python, clustering, spatio-temporal-data, big-data

I'm working with a dataset with latitude, longitude and date-time. I have millions of points per day and I want to group them using a clustering algorithm.

I read this question [Clustering geographic points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243019/clustering-geographic-points) but in my case I don't have an expected number of clusters. I explored `HDBSCAN` but it only accepts 2 features (lat lon in radians).

The idea is to get clusters of my datapoints regrouping nearest points in location and time together. So depending on the day, the output should change.

Is there a way to do a spatiotemporal clustering that includes the 3 features?

Comment: Is this a global data set or is it on a small enough region that it can be considered flat?

Comment: thanks for the question. The region can be considered flat (geodetic point of view)